# Scraping wallets address on etherscan to .XLMS

Tags: web-scraping, ethereum

I'm a student in IT Big Data, I'm currently working on a school project where I want to create a graph of all recent transaction. But can't find a good way to get the data correctly from the API anybody has an idea to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal recommendation is to not use Etherscan, and instead to use [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/) and an RPC provider like [infura](https://infura.io/) or [alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/) - or if you're feeling ambitious, run your own node. Instantiate a provider and listen for the `block` event: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--events. If you want to listen for EIP-20 token transfers only, you can use the answer in this question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87643/how-to-listen-to-contract-events-using-ethers-js

Getting the data manually might seem more complicated, but it's actually more simple (and quicker/more customizable!) than polling the Etherscan API.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks for your answer, I chose to work with infura and JS here is the ways i made it work, with that you ll get all the transaction from 150 blocks on mainnet :

```js
async function data() {
    var Web3 = require('web3');
    var provider = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/apikey';
    var web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider);
    var web3 = new Web3(web3Provider);
    console.log("transaction per block");
    var k= 15623650;
    for(var j= 15623650;k-j<150;j--){
        var a;
        var onumber_of_transaction_by_block = await web3.eth.getBlockTransactionCount(j).then(a = this);
        var Number_by_block =await Number(onumber_of_transaction_by_block);
        for(var i=1;i<=Number_by_block-1;i++){
            console.log("transaction");
            var transaction = await web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(j , i);
            console.log("block :" + j + ", transaction :" + i)  
       }
}
```